# Android scale ImageView's frame

Tags: android

I have an `imageview` and i want to scale it with it's frame!
I used `imageView.setScaleX()` but this method only scales image within and image view X, Y, width and Height are the same.
What must i do to resize `imageview` with image?

[image: see this figure]

Comment: Please check google already provide some properties of image view.

Comment: why not change height instead scaleX?

Comment: set    android:scaleType="center".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @saeid . I've replaced setScale with setWidth and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property scaleType to the ImageView XML like this:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

More info:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I've no problem to show image. I want to adjust image bounds with scale.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to height change automatically when width changed, use this custom ImageView.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()
                    / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            int maxHeight;
            try {
                Field f = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mMaxHeight");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                maxHeight = (Integer) f.get(this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                maxHeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height > maxHeight ? maxHeight : height);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```